# Accessing an array outside an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, angular

all! I have an ajax call grabbing the results of an API. When I try to access that array outside the call, it's blank. Help?

In the code below, I get the list of properties, then assign the results to the "mlsArray" variable. When I console log it inside main, I get the desired result.

However, if I later call getHomes, the array is empty.

```
main(auth) {
$.ajax({async: false,
    url: "https://api.simplyrets.com/properties? 
limit=500&lastId=0&status=active&maxprice=" +
    this.maximum + "&type=residential",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    // authorize with the API credentials
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  " + auth);
    },
    success: function(res) {
     this.mlsArray  = Object.assign([], res);
     console.log(this.mlsArray);
    }
  });
}

 getHomes() {
  console.log(this.mlsArray);
 }
}
```

Comment: `success: function(res) { console.log(this); ` It is not what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you. I will read up on that and be back asap.

Comment: You have tagged your question with Angular so why are you using jQuery to make a request and not using the HttpClient service? This code is not how you do things the Angular way.

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with here is javascript `this` "scoping" rules. The context of a function ( by default ) takes on the context of the object that invokes it ( see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this ).

When you're invoking the function `success`, you need to `bind` the context to the one you want inside the function:

```js
success: function (res) {
 // do things ...
}.bind(this)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the *this* here refers to the ajax *object*.

```
this.mlsArray  = Object.assign([], res);
```

wherein the *this* here below refers to the window object which has all the global properties and methods.

```
getHomes() {
  console.log(this.mlsArray);
 }
```

1.Either bind the values to the window object by using

```
success: function (res) {
 this.mlsArray  = Object.assign([], res);
 console.log(this.mlsArray);
}.bind(this)
```

or

2. make mlsArray as a global variable and refrain from using *this* keyword.

   success: function (res) {
        mlsArray  = Object.assign([], res);
        console.log(mlsArray);
       }

and in getHomes like below

```
getHomes() {
  console.log(mlsArray);
 }
```

Comment: there is no need for a global

Comment: yes no need for it when you are using the first option. but if not using the first option, is it not needed to have a global variable ? enlighten me sir :)

Answer (score -1):

You should assign the value from the `success` part of your ajax call into a global variable so that you could access it even inside outside the `main()` function.

Comment: Isn't this what I am trying to do with: 

 this.mlsArray  = Object.assign([], res);

(serious question)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the full code in context of your problem and you're not actually assigning it if do not have any prior definition/initialization of the 'mlsArray' variable instead of just downvoting answers. Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted it because making a global is a bad answer. It is a poor answer.

Comment: Ah I see, I will take that into consideration next time. Thanks.